# How to upload a full AngularJS application to Azure?

Tags: angularjs, azure

I have created a full AngularJS application which until now I used Gulp and my own localhost to test, develop and let others use it.

Now I want to use Azure (since as a student I received a free account) to upload my app.
I've found a lot of articles showing how to deploy a "One page app" and this is not my case, none of those guides shows what to do if you ALREADY have the angularJS app ready and working on your pc and just want to deploy and integrate it on Azure.

Not sure if relevant, but this is a description of my AngularJS app:

My angularJS application consists:

- Bower components
- Node_modules
- The angular library

App library contains:

- index.html + 404.html
- images library
- Scripts: app.js + 8 more js files.
- Styles library (CSS+less)
- Views: over 15 html files.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 but it seems impossible to just deploy my whole app, what are the options? And is it even possible because I start to lose hope.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't gulp "build" and create a minified and uglified version?

Comment: But still how do I use it on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this blog post, You will need to use Azure Local git continuous deployment feature to get the node packages and other bower packages sorted out.

[Create a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/)